# ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush(); not working in VS C#

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to set a background on a page of my app.

To do so, many people have said I need to use the `ImageBrush` object. But, I get errors when  I try to initialize the following line of code:

```
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: It says, "The type or namespace name 'ImageBrush' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Add a reference to [PresentationCore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Forms does not support ImageBrush.  You can just set the BackgroundImage property of a page.

```
<ContentPage BackgroundImage="myImage.png" ... >
```

Comment: So I tried adding the line: `BackgroundImage="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/07/08/24/ramadan-2291896_1280.png"` but the project would not build. This is my whole code: `<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage"
             Title="Hello"
             Padding="10,290,10,200"
             BackgroundImage="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/07/08/24/ramadan-2291896_1280.png">
`

Comment: "The property 'Content' is set more than once."

Comment: that has nothing to do with the BackgroundImage

Comment: I removed only the BackgroundImage and the project builds and runs correctly.

Comment: I attempted to add the BackgroundImage line back into the ContentPage tag, and now there are no errors but the build simply crashes.

Comment: your background image needs to be the name of a file placed in the resources folder (iOS) or drawable folder (Android). 

You are trying to load an image from the web, which isn't done the way you try it. 

Based on your questions, I would strongly advice you to look into the tutorials and resources on the xamarin website.